# Check if object has PropertyChanged Event attached to it

Tags: c#, wpf

When my window is loaded, I have an ObservableCollection that is populated and a PropertyChanged event is added to each item. However, after the initial loading items can be added to the ObservableCollection. I want to be able to listen for collection changes on the ObservableCollection, check if an item was added and then attach an event listener to it if it was added.

To do this, I'd like to be able to check if the PropertyChanged property is defined for each individual item and attach a PropertyChanged event if not.

And here is my code:

```
items.CollectionChanged += (object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) =>
{
    foreach (var item in items.Where(o => o.PropertyChanged == null)) //error here
    {
        item.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
    }
};
```

However, I'm getting a compilation error saying:

> The event 'ModelBase.PropertyChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Any ideas how to check if an object has its PropertyChanged property event defined?

Comment: You say 'defined' but you probably mean 'assigned'. Please clarify, see the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you are attempting to avoid subscribing to the `PropertyChanged` event multiple times. You can use the `NewItems` property of the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` to do this.

```
if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count != 0)
{
    foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.NewItems)
        item.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
}
```

You can also use `OldItems` to unscubscribe.

```
if (e.OldItems != null && e.OldItems.Count != 0)
{
    foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.OldItems)
        item.PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
}
```

If you also have items in your collection that do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` you can combine this with Jonathan Allen's answer to filter the list.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the `OldItems` and `NewItems` property of the NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.

With a `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`, this works for all values of `e.Action`, except `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset`.

```
items.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.OldItems != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.OldItems.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
        {
            item.PropertyChanged -= Item_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }
    if (e.NewItems != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.NewItems.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
        {
            item.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, gave the accepted answer to Derrick because he was first though.

Answer (score 1):

```
items.CollectionChanged += (object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) =>
{
    foreach (var item in items.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>()) //filter the list
    {
        item.PropertyChanged += Item_PropertyChanged;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
Use this at every class you want to implement PropertyChange method.